# Envio de datos por fetch a node / expressJs

Tags: html5, nodejs, express, fetch, pug

Buen día, 
Estoy trabajando con un login con **node.js / expressJs** y necesito mandar uno valor al servidor a través fetch sin embargo no logro hacer que el servidor los reconozca, por lo que veo ni siquiera los recibe.

Tengo un formulario en el **HTML/PUG**, el cual captura los datos de usuario y contraseñas para mandarlos al servidor y estos sean validados, sin embargo también requiero enviar un valor alojado en el **sessionstorage**, para esto me apoyo de un **JS** el cual esta enlazado en el mismo HTLM.

***HTML / Pug***

```
    section.container
    div.login
        form( id="login", action="/valCreden/" method="POST")
            //- form(action="/valCreden/"+session, method="post")
            input(type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Ingrese su correo" required)
            input(type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" required)
            //- input(type="hidden", name="session" id="token" )
            input(type="submit",  value="Iniciar Sesion")
        a(href="/registrarse", ) Registrarse
    script(src="../js/app.js")
```

***JS***

Del lado del servidor, tengo un **eventListener** en el cual en el momento que se presenta el evento **submit**, activa la función encargada de hacer el envío a través de **fetch**.

```
var login = document.getElementById("login");
login.addEventListener( "submit", myFunction );


function myFunction(){
   localStorage.setItem('token2', 'valorToken2');
   var session = localStorage.getItem( 'token' );
   console.log( `Linea 9 - El token es: ${session}` );
   console.log(session);
   var usu = document.getElementsByName( 'usuario' ).value;
   var pas = document.getElementsByName( 'contraseña' ).value;

   // FETCH:
   var myHeader = new headers();
   var requ = {
      method : 'POST',
      headers : myHeader,
      usuario : usu,
      contraseña : pas,
      sesi : session
   };
  var myRequest = new Request( 'http://localhost:3000/valCreden/', requ );

   fetch( myRequest, {credentials: 'include'} ) 
       .then( ( res )=>{
           if ( res.ok ){
               console.log( `Respuesta de red OK: ${res}` )
           }
       } )
       .catch( (error)=> { console.log( error ) } );
  };
```

Como pueden ver el **fetch** envía a través de un objeto todos los datos del formulario como el valor alojado en el sessionstorage.

***Controlador en ExpressJs***

```
// Funcion que valida las credenciales ingresadas.
MovieController.valCreden = (req, res, next)=>{
  let credenciales = {
      usuario : req.body.usuario,
      contraseña : req.body.contraseña,
      session : req.body.sesi
  }
MovieModel.valCreden( credenciales, (err, data)=>{
    console.log( ` Linea 58 - El token es: ${credenciales.session}` )
```

Creo que el problema proviene del **JS**, por alguna razón este no se ejecuta ya que en la consola no me aparecen los console.log que he escrito, sin embargo tampoco se si hay algún error en el la funcion **fetch**.

Espero puedan ayudarme. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: No he visto el código a detalle, pero a primera vista **no estás previniendo el submit por defecto** del formulario, el cual incurre en una petición HTTP normal (con redirección), haciendo posible que el código ajax nunca se ejecute. Agrega como parámetro del listener el evento y como primera línea ejecuta `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como @gugadev te comenta, debes prevenir el comportamiento por defecto del elemento tipo `submit`, porque es muy probable que la petición `fetch` no se realice. Sin embargo, además de dicho detalle, tienes otros problemas al enviar los datos desde el cliente, e imagino que también tienes problemas en el lado del servidor, al manejar los datos recibidos.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea enviar datos a un servidor Node/Express, usando el método [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) mediante una solicitud tipo `POST`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para lograr el objetivo vamos a realizar algunos cambios en nuestros métodos y la forma en la que usamos los mismos.

El primer cambio lo haremos en la plantilla `pug`, el cambio es sutil pero muy importante. En tu plantilla usas `document.getElementsByName`, y luego intentas capturar el valor devuelto por `value`. Sin embargo, según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName), dicho método devuelve una lista de nodos cuyo atributo `name` coincida con el valor que pasamos a nuestro método. Por lo tanto, cuando intentas hacer `document.getElementsByName('user').value`, el resultado será: `undefined`, ya que `value` no está definido en la lista de nodos.

Dicho lo anterior, cambiaremos los atributos `name` por atributos `id` en nuestra plantilla, para poder usar de esta manera el método `document.getElementById`

**index.pug**

```
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= message
    section.container
      div.login
        form( id="login", action="/valCreden/" method="POST")
          input(type="text" id="user" placeholder="email" required)
          input(type="password" id="password" placeholder="password" required)
          input(type="submit",  value="Sign in")
        a(href="/registrarse", ) Sign Up
      script(src="/js/app.js", type="text/javascript")
```

Ahora haremos los cambios en nuestro archivo Javascript.

Un cambio importante es la forma en la que implementas las opciones que pasas el objeto `request`, también debemos prevenir que el elemento `submit` realice el envío de los datos del `form`, ya que eso evitaría que se ejecutara nuestra solicitud `fetch`. Adicionalmente, cambiaremos la forma de capturar los valores de los elementos `input`, usando [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

**opciones**

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      'user': user,
      'password': password,
      'session': session
    })
}
```

Como puedes apreciar usaremos el atributo `body` y le pasaremos como valor un objeto del tipo [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), el cual contendrá los valores (par *clave: valor*) de los datos.

En la documentación de [`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request), nos indica claramente el tipo de objetos aceptados por el atributo `body`.

**app.js**

```
const login = document.getElementById('login');

login.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); // <- Se previene el comportamiento por defecto del elemento
  localStorage.setItem('token', 'value of token');
  const session = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const user = document.getElementById('user').value; // <- Usamos getElementById
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  let myHeaders = new Headers();

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      'user': user,
      'password': password,
      'session': session
    }),
  }

  let myRequest = new Request('http://localhost:3000/valCreden/', options);
  fetch(myRequest, {credentials: 'include'})
    .then((res) => {
      if(res.ok) {
        console.log('Ok');
        return res.json(); // <- parseamos el response y lo devolvemos a nuestra función
      }

    })
    .then((resParsed) => {
      console.log(resParsed); // <- mostramos los datos recibidos, luego de ser parseados
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Por último haremos cambios en nuestro servidor.

Para este ejemplo usaré una implementación mínima de Express con los elementos básicos para que todo funcione de acuerdo a lo que necesitamos.

Uno de los cambios importantes, es usar un `parser` para poder usar el objeto `body` de nuestra solicitud. Express 4.16.0 y superior incluye los métodos `json()` y `urlencoded()`, los cuales nos sirven para capturar y parsear los datos del `body` de la solicitud. Para usarlos debemos escribir lo siguiente:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
});
```

Luego, para capturar los datos que vienen en el cuerpo de nuestra solicitud haremos lo siguiente:

```
let data = req.body;
```

Así en el objeto `data` tendremos los valores que han sido enviados usando el método `fetch` en el cuerpo de dicha solicitud.

**index.js**

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {title: 'Using Fetch with Node/Express', message: 'Try Me!'});
});

app.post('/valCreden', (req, res) => {
  let data = req.body;
  console.log(data);
  res.status(200).json(data); // <- enviamos de regreso los datos recibidos
});

app.listen(3000, (err) => {
  if(err) console.log(err);
  console.info('App started');
});
```

Como puedes apreciar, los cambios son sutiles, pero importantes.

De esta forma puedes enviar los datos que necesites a tu servidor y trabajar con ellos.

Una captura del resultado en el servidor:

[image: Resultado en servidor]

Aquí una captura del resultado en el navegador con la consola abierta para ver la respuesta del servidor:

[image: Resultado en el navegador]

Espero que sea la respuesta que esperabas y logres solucionar el problema.

Comment: Antes que nada quiero agradecerte tu excelente respuesta, Eres de los pocos usuarios que he visto que dan una respuesta sumamente bien estructurada. Es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Es bueno ver que en esta comunidad hay gente que realmente se toma la molestia para ayudar a otros developers. Te agradezco la ayuda.